# How to add items of list as keys to an object in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `Redux` with `Reactjs`.

According to [Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions):

> return new state objects, instead of mutating the previous state.

I have an object with its present state as:

```js
state = [..., {id: 6, details: []}, ..., ...]
```

and I have an array of keys (all strings and unique) like this:

```js
list: ["A", "B", "C"]
```

In `javascript`, if I do like this:

```js
for (const key of list) {
  exampleDetails[key] = null
}
```

I get my desired output:

```js
exampleDetails // ["A": null, "B": null, "C": null]
exampleDetails["A"] // null <= what I actually need
```

But, how to get this next state the redux way, that is, without mutation?

```js
switch(state = [], action) {
  case 'MY_ACTION':
    return state.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === action.id) {
        return {
          id: obj.id,
          details: [
            ...obj.details,
            /* what to do here? where list is => action.list */
          ]
        }
      } else return obj
    })
  default:
    return state
}
```

## EDIT

I didn't mean to say that I was writing something this in the code:

```js
["A": null, "B": null, "C": null]
```

This is what I am getting as an output in the browser console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
switch(state = [], action) {
  case 'MY_ACTION':
    return state.map(obj => 
      (obj.id === action.id ? {...obj, details: action.list.reduce((acc, element) => { acc[element] = null; return acc; }, {}) } : obj)
    )
  default:
    return state
}
```

I think you are mixing up the concept between array and object. What you are trying to achieve is an object with the list element as the key.

Comment: your reducer updates `details` as `["A", "B", "C"]`, see EDIT what I actually need

Comment: the `details` is now `[{"A": null}, {"B": null}, {"C": null}]`, this is not what I want, please see the output in EDIT

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve... your edit simply show you want a list of object which is [{"A": null}, {"B": null}, {"C": null}]

Unless what you want is {"A": null, "B": null, "C":null}

Comment: In `const exampleDetails = [{"A": null}, {"B": null}, {"C": null}]`, `exampleDetails["A"]` gives me `undefined`, whereas in my EDIT, `exampleDetails["A"]` is giving me `null`, that's the difference.

Comment: Updated answer, but you are certainly mixing up the concept between array and object

Comment: You're right, object should be used instead of array